# Grouping entries from PostgreSQL database by their week or month based on timestamp value?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have been trying to resolve a solution to this for a while now but due to my inexperience with both postgres(and SQL in general) and Django ORM I haven't been able to get a result that I can use.

I have this model:

```
class EventItem(models.Model):
    Id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    StartTime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    EndTime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    Duration = models.TimeField(null=True)
    Creator = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

and I want to get the EventItems and group the entries by their week and/or month. So for every week starting from the earliest entry group all of the events for that week into one group.

Right now I am able to return the week number for each individual item by doing this:

```
weeks = EventItem.objects.annotate(week=ExtractWeek('StartTime')).values('week')
```

But this obviously doesn't group the results and I also need to keep the columns from the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use ExtractWeek because that just gets an integer value of the week in the year, e.g. 44, this can cause clashes across datasets that exceed a year.

What you will want to use is `TruncWeek` which essentially caps a data value at the Monday of that week. You can combine this with `order_by()` to get your data grouped together.

```py
from django.db.models.functions import TruncWeek

weeks = EventItem.objects.annotate(week=TruncWeek('StartTime').order_by('week')
```

Comment: Thank you this was what I was looking for. Although, ideally I would want the results to be grouped by the week also which I am having trouble with too. I have been trying something like `EventItem.objects.all().values().annotate(week=TruncWeek('StartTime')).annotate(count=Count('week')).order_by('-count')` but that just annotates '1' to every result.

Comment: The `order_by('week')` in my answer will group together by week, if you want to group the start times within that you can do `order_by('StartTime','week')`

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I asked the wrong question. I was attempting to get a count of the number of events in each week so I could know which week had the most events. I was able to get a workable result by doing `week_events.values('week').order_by('week').annotate(count=Count('week'))`